# React native (ios). "saveToCameraRoll" error - "PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

When I try to save an image to the phone (emulator IPhone 11 - iOS 13.1) gallery:

```
import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll";

...

CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll('https://example.com/images/1.jpg', 'photo')
.then(() => {
  alert('Saved to photos');
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('err:', err);
});
```

, it gives me an error:

> err: [Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain
>   error -1.)]

I added these lines to the file "Info.plist":

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library</string>
```

And run command in "ios" folder:

```
pod update
pod install
```

But the error still remains. Is there anything I have to do to clean up the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced the same situation, here's how i solved it:

I've downloaded the file using `rn-fetch-blob`:

```
let file
RNFetchBlob
    .config({
        fileCache: true,
        appendExt: path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.')+1, path.length)
           //get the file's extension from the URL it's coming from and append to the file name that RNFectchBlob will create locally
    })
    .fetch('GET', path) //GET request to URL which has your file
    .then((res) => {
        file = res //var 'file' is the temp object which contains all data from our file
    })
```

with the file saved locally on your app we can now call `CameraRoll` to save the file:

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(file.path())
.then(Alert.alert("Done!", "Your file has been saved."))
```

Comment: Yes, I found the same solution. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps someone,

I got the same error in the React Native Cameraroll version 4.1.2. (iOS)

"react-native": "0.63.3".

I solved the issue by **prefixing "file://" in the image path** for saveToCameraRoll/save method.